# $(ab+bc+ca)^3=abc(a+b+c)^3$, prove that $a,b,c$ are in $G.P.$

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, geometric-progressions

Suppose $a,b,c$ are non-zero real numbers such that
$$(ab+bc+ca)^3=abc.(a+b+c)^3$$
Prove that $a,b,c$ must be terms of a $G.P.$

> *I simplified this equation too*
> $$(ab)^3+(bc)^3+(ca)^3=abc.(a^3+b^3+c^3)$$
> I tried to subtract $3(abc)^2$ from both sides and it gave a factorised form.
> $$(ab+bc+ca).((ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2-abc.(a+b+c))=abc.(a+b+c).(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$$
> How can I proceed after that?

Comment: I don't think your simplification is correct.

Comment: I used the formula $(a+b+c)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$.

Comment: You are right. I made an error myself.

Comment: Expand $(ab-c^2)(ac-b^2)(bc-a^2)$

Comment: @Empy2
Taking the $R.H.S$ to the $L.H.S$ and we get $(ab-c^2)(ca-b^2)(bc-a^2)$.

Comment: Another method found [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h275238p1489639)

Comment: Is there any easier method for the factorisation?

Comment: Go to the above link for easier method

Answer (score 2):

This one is a long-way of solving (**With a very obvious result**).
\begin{gather*}
\implies(ab+bc+ca)^3-abc(a+b+c)^3=0\\
\end{gather*}
\begin{multline*}
\implies (a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3+3a^2b^3c+3a^2bc^3+3a^3b^2c+3ab^2c^3+3a^3bc^2+3ab^3c^2)-\\abc(a^3+b^3+c^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+3b^2c+3bc^2+3c^2a+3ca^2)=0
\end{multline*}

After simplifying
\begin{equation}
\implies a^3b^3+b^3c^3+c^3a^3-a^4bc-ab^4c-abc^4=0
\end{equation}
Factorising this will give
\begin{equation}
\implies(ab-c^2)(bc-a^2)(ca-b^2)=0
\end{equation}
Therefore, a,b,c must be in G.P.

Answer (score 1):

There was a good answer posted by @Albusdumbledore that was deleted. I am just  reproducing that answer and will delete mine if the other is undeleted.

The suggestion was to write $a = q, b = q r$ and $c = q r k$. Naturally, since $a,b,c \ne 0$, we also have $q,r,k \ne 0$. Plugging this into the relation, one concludes that $r, k$ must satisfy the relation
$$
(k-r) \left(k^2 r-1\right) \left(k r^2-1\right)=0
$$

All solutions lead to GP's. More specifically,

Case 1. If $k=r$, $a=q$, $b = r q$ and $c= r^2 q$ are consecutive terms in a GP with ratio $r$.

Case 2. If $k=\frac{1}{r^2}$ then $c=\frac{1}{r^2} q$, $a = q$ and $b=rq$ are (nonconsecutive) terms in a GP with ratio $r$

Case 3. If $k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$ then $c= \frac 1r q$, $a=q$ and $b= rq$ are (nonconsecutive) terms in a GP with ratio $\sqrt{r}$.

Case 4. If $k=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$ then $a=q$, $c=-\sqrt{r} q$, $b = rq$ are consecutive terms in a GP with ratio $-\sqrt{r}$